# Making an AST in Go

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree, go-interface

I'm writing a parser for a custom language in go. My problem is that each node on the syntax tree is different based on it's type (be it an `if` or a `variableDef` or a `funcDef`) and thus has different values, but I need to have pointers that can point at any of them, to give it treeish functionality.

Someone suggested having an `interface`, with something like a `describe` method (implementation-dependent) that described the node, but then the problem is that it'll return different things based on the node that is it. (A `funcDef` would give `args []variableDef` and `body []node`, but an if would give `cond bin` and `body []node`, and a variable def would have `type typ` and `name string`)

I originally wrote this in JS and used the flexibility of JSON to my advantage. I have heard that Go has built-in JSON support but I don't think i want to go down that route.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/

Comment: @BurakSerdar correct me if i'm wrong, but I think that's a package for parsing _Go_ modules, and not really what I want

Comment: Correct. But it also contains the ast for go, and you can implement something similar for yourself.

Comment: For instance: https://golang.org/src/go/ast/ast.go?s=1405:1446#L29 shows an example interface for Expression nodes.